# Access SQL : How to create a crosstab query with a potentially empty row

Tags: ms-access, pivot

Suppose I have a database that contains two different types of information about certain unique objects, say their 'State' and 'Condition' to give a name to their classifiers. The State can take the values A, B, C or D, the condition the values X or Y. Depending on where I am sourcing data from, sometimes this database lacks entries for a particular pair.

From this data, I'd like to make a crosstab query that shows the count of data with a given State and Condition combination, but to have it still yield a row even when a given row is a 0. For example, I'd like the following table:

```
Unit | State | Condition
 1   |  A    |     X
 2   |  B    |     Y
 3   |  C    |     X
 4   |  B    |     Y
 5   |  B    |     X
 6   |  B    |     Y
 7   |  C    |     X
```

To produce the following crosstab:

```
Count |   X   |   Y
  A   |   1   |   0  
  B   |   1   |   3  
  C   |   2   |   0  
  D   |   0   |   0
```

Any help that would leave blanks instead of zeroes is fit for purpose as well, these are being pasted into a template Excel document that requires each crosstab to have an exact dimension.

What I've Tried:

The standard crosstab SQL

```
TRANSFORM Count(Unit) 
SELECT Condition 
FROM Sheet
GROUP BY Count(Unit)
PIVOT State;
```

obviously doesn't work as it doesn't raise the possibility of a D occurring. PIVOTing by a nested IIf that explicitly names D as a possible value does nothing either, nor does combining it with an Nz() around the TRANSFORM clause variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TRANSFORM Count(sheet.unit) AS CountOfunit
SELECT AllStates.state
FROM AllStates LEFT JOIN sheet ON AllStates.state = sheet.state
GROUP BY AllStates.state
PIVOT sheet.condition;
```

This uses a table "AllStates" that has a row for each state you want to force into the result.  It will produce an extra column for entries that are neither Condition X nor Condition Y - that's where the forced entry for state D ends up, even though the count is 0.

If you have a relatively small number of conditions, you can use this instead:

```
SELECT AllStates.state, Sum(IIf([condition]="x",1,0)) AS X, Sum(IIf([condition]="Y",1,0)) AS Y
FROM AllStates LEFT JOIN sheet ON AllStates.state = sheet.state
GROUP BY AllStates.state;
```

Unlike a crosstab, though, this won't automatically add new columns when new condition codes are added to the data.  It can also be cumbersome if you have many condition codes.

Comment: "an extra column" -> "an extra row"

Comment: @Andre - well, it creates a new row for State D (which was the requirement), but it also creates a new column for "<>" for Condition values that are Null (which may not be acceptable if the Excel formats are fixed at 1 column per condition).  That's why I provided the alternative solution as well.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I thought it was a simple mixup of "row" and "column" (I have a colleague who does this all the time). But the extra explanation is helpful.